# custom Tab Builder with tabs_on_rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, tabs

I have use [tabs_on_rails](http://github.com/weppos/tabs_on_rails) plugin to do tabs view.
and its documentation told me that we can custom a builder to override methods like

- open_tabs: the method called before the tab set
- close_tabs: the method called after the tab set
- tab_for: the method called to create a single tab item

the problem is I don't know where to put the override code? Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Topley is right but not enough.
You should put the particular class input /lib and name it as menu_tab_builder.rb
Then you will find that it still doesn't work because of Rails3.
In addition, you need to add `open_tabs` and `close_tabs` function.

```
# the following is necessary to make this rails3 compatible
def open_tabs(options = {})
   @context.tag("ul", options, open = true)
end
```

```
  # the following is necessary to make this rails3 compatible
  def close_tabs(options = {})
    "".html_safe
  end
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the custom builder class in a file within your Rails application's `/lib` directory then it will be automatically loaded by Rails.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have put the class in a rb file within /lib, but it still can't work. It output "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::MenuTabBuilder"? why?

Answer (score 0):

Do place custom builder class file in /config/initializers directory within your application and restart your server.